# Define a function that extract a float and do operation

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a column with the following type of values:

[image]

I have to define a function that convert column Diameter in float and manage that kind of exception. In particular:

- when is 42x54 then make the operation: sqrt(42^2+54^2)
- when is Steel then return a NaN value

Comment: please provide a reproducible input (text not image!) and the matching expected output

Comment: What does your current attempt at writing this function look like? So we can further point you in the right direction.

Comment: my attempt is using the "try-except" construction. First I try to convert in float. When this is not impossible, convert the data like "42x50" in a list like [42,50]. Then take the first and second element of this list to do the operation. If all this doesn't work then return NaN. I try various construction but every time something is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex to get the numbers, then square them with [`pow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html), [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) the columns, and get the square root with [`numpy.sqrt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['Diameter2'] = np.sqrt(df['Diameter']
                          .str.extract('(\d+)(?:\s*x\s*(\d+))?')
                          .astype(float).pow(2)
                          .sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
                          )
```

output:

```
  Diameter  Diameter2
0       44  44.000000
1  42 x 54  68.410526
2    Steel        NaN
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ElA5q/1)

```
(\d+)              # capture a number
(?:\s*x\s*(\d+))?  # capture a number (optionally) if preceded by x with optional spaces
```

Comment: thank you. Can I ask you what is the function of the command extract('(\d+)(?:\s*x\s*(\d+))?') ?

Comment: This is a regular expression, I'm adding some details